# Fedora 18 in VM locks the CD drive

Tags: fedora, mount, windows, vmware

I have windows 7 and I installed VMware (VMware-player-5.0,2-1031769) and want to put fedora 18 in it but after complete installation is done I'm getting the below error:

> The guest operating system has locked the cd-rom door and is probably using the cd-rom which can prevent the guest from recognition media changes. If possible eject the CD-ROM from inside the guest before the disconnection.

Disconnect anyway and override the lock?

Can anyone help me to come out of this problem...

Comment: Doubtful that it can be reproduced 5 years later. The OS versions in question are long beyond their advertized lifetime

Answer (score 0):

The solution probably depends on it which application has locked the drive. A reboot of the VM should solve the problem (and be the easiest way to do so). A disconnect by the hypervisor should not cause problems, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have installed Fedora 16 instead of Fedora 18 in VM and by doing this my VMPlayer started running with Fedora successfully .